# JDBC rollback failed

Tags: java, hibernate, excepciones, jdbc, derby

Actualmente estoy en un proyecto donde se utiliza Hibernate (3.6.10.Final) + DerbyDB, llevo mucho tiempo bloqueado con un problema.

Lo que quiero hacer es una función que añada instancias de `C` dentro del `set<B>` que esta dentro de la clase `A`. A continuación doy más información sobre lo que tengo implementado

Este es el UML de las clases que estoy usando:

[image: UML]

El mapping lo hago a través de un fichero XML `Mapping.hbm.xml`, uso *one-to-many* dentro de la clase `A` y en la clase `B` se utiliza *many-to-one*.

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.bla.A" table="A">

        <id name="id" column="ID" type="long">
            <generator class="hilo" />
        </id>

        <set name="myB" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="A_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="com.bla.B" />
        </set>

    </class>

    <class name="com.bla.B" table="B">

        <id name="id" column="ID" type="long">
            <generator class="hilo" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="myA" not-null="false" lazy="false"
            column="A_ID" />

        <joined-subclass name="com.bla.C" lazy="false"
            table="C">
            <key column="ID" />
            <property name="name" column="NAME" not-null="true" />
            <property name="bla" type="text" length="2000" column="BLA"
                not-null="true" />
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

La función que añade todos los `C` dentro del `Set<B>` es la siguiente:

```
public static void addNewCsToA(A a, Set<C> cs) {

    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = Mediator.getSession(); // Starts a new session
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
        System.out.println("PRE setting");
        B b = null;
        for (C c : cs) {

            c.setA(a);
            b = (B) c;
            session.save(b);
            System.out.println("B saved");
        }
        a.addCs(cs);
        session.update(a);
        System.out.println("A updated");
        System.out.println("flush");
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("commited");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (session != null && session.getTransaction() != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el código cuando llega el momento de hacer el flush, salta una `HibernateException` que indica que el rollback que se realiza en el catch ha fallado. Entra en el cache porque intento insertar 2 `C` con el mismo Primary Key, en teoría debería de hacer un rollback y devolver el error, pero falla el rollback.

**EDIT:** Añado el log completo

> may 03, 2018 4:07:12 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse 
>   mapMappableContainerException
>   GRAVE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:200)
>       at com.bla.Controller.addNewCsToA(Controller.java:171)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Se ha encontrado un error de protocolo de red y se ha terminado la conexión: El comando solicitado ha encontrado una condición no estructurada y específica de la implantación para la que no había ningún mensaje estructurado (puede encontrar más información en el archivo derby.log del servidor)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.rollback(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
>       ... 44 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Se ha encontrado un error de protocolo de red y se ha terminado la conexión: El comando solicitado ha encontrado una condición no estructurada y específica de la implantación para la que no había ningún mensaje estructurado (puede encontrar más información en el archivo derby.log del servidor)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.copyAsUnchainedSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Sqlca.chainDeferredExceptionsToAgentOrAsConnectionWarnings(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Sqlca.getJDBCMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2438)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2875)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at com.bla.Controller.addNewCsToA(Controller.java:171)
>       ... 43 more

**EDIT2:** Añado el log cuando no se realiza el rollback, la operación que realizo es insertar 2 veces el objeto con la misma PK (en teoría debería de realizar rollback y devolver error)

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.bla.C]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2455)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2875)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at com.bla.Controller.addNewCsToA(Controller.java:171)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.*handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 0, SQLSTATE: XJ001, SQLERRMC: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionXJ001.U
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2438)
>       ... 58 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 0, SQLSTATE: XJ001, SQLERRMC: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionXJ001.U
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute*(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
>       ... 60 more

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe esta excepción?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar todo lo que te sale en el log

Comment: Prueba eliminando (por ahora) el rollback y dejando sólo el printStackTrace, con eso deberíamos ver cual es la excepción original

Comment: acabo de añadir el log que me sale cuando comento el rollback